# How to get the sum of from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the sum from both the tables?

1. `res_transactions`
2. `TRANS_ADD`

Queries:

```
select 
    tranid, Qty, Price 
from 
    res_transactions 
where 
    order_no = '16104' 
    and tranid = '506060' 
order by
    tranid asc

select 
    FTRN, Qty, Price 
from 
    TRANS_ADD  
where 
    FTRN = '506060'
```

Kindly find the attached snapshot for more info

Excepted output is

```
 Qty * Price
```

Total Price should be: **13.6**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(result) as sumresult from 
    (select Qty * Price as result from res_transactions where order_no='16104' and tranid='506060'
     union all
     select Qty * Price as result from TRANS_ADD  where FTRN='506060'
     )t
```

Answer (score 2):

To get sum from res_transactions:

```
SELECT TRANID AS ID, SUM(QTY*PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM RES_TRANSACTIONS WHERE ORDER_NO='16104' AND TRANID='506060'
GROUP BY TRANID
```

Same for TRANS_ADD:

```
SELECT FTRN AS ID, SUM(QTY*PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM TRANS_ADD  WHERE FTRN='506060'
GROUP BY FTRN
```

So if you want to find sum of these two values you can use [union all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) keyword. **Do not use union** because it will delete duplicated rows.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL FROM (
    SELECT TRANID AS ID, SUM(QTY*PRICE) AS TOTAL FROM RES_TRANSACTIONS WHERE ORDER_NO='16104' AND TRANID='506060' GROUP BY TRANID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FTRN AS ID, SUM(QTY*PRICE) AS TOTAL FROM TRANS_ADD  WHERE FTRN='506060' GROUP BY FTRN
) TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Qty,Price,Qty*Price
FROM TRANS_ADD T,res_transactions R 
WHERE T.FTRN=R.tranid
AND T.FTRN=506060
AND R.order_no = 16104;
```

Is it your expected output....????